# rails parsing xml to show json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xml

I'm trying to convert some XML into JSON

This is what I have so far

```
def skiddle_api
  skiddlexml = 'http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml'
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(skiddlexml))
  doc.css('event#12987613').css('ticket').each do |node|
    children = node.children
      byebug
    @ticket_json = {
      'name' => children.css('name').inner_text
      'facevalue' => children.css('faceValue').inner_text
    }
  end
  respond_to do |format|
     format.json  { render :json => {:ticket => @ticket_json } }
  end
end
```

The event I have on here at the moment has 5-8 different ticket types

I'm wanting each ticket type to show as JSON format like this:

```
{
    "ticket": {
        "name": "Return Coach Ticket - Glasgow - Coach A"
        "faceValue": "20.00"
    }
    "ticket": {
        "name": "Return Coach Ticket - Manchester - Coach B"
        "faceValue": "25.00"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you replace `@ticket_json` each time here:

```
@ticket_json = {
  'name' => children.css('name').inner_text,
  'facevalue' => children.css('faceValue').inner_text
}
```

So you need to assign a new value each time, but `@ticket_json` can't be a hash, it must be an array of hashes in order for it to work (you can't have duplicate keys in a hash, and your example has duplicate keys).

The solution then will be to create an array instead of hash **outside the each loop** and add a ticket on each iteration, something like this:

```
def skiddle_api
  skiddlexml = 'http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml'
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(skiddlexml))

  @ticket_json = []

  doc.css('event#12987613').css('ticket').each do |node|
    children = node.children
    @ticket_json << {
      'name' => children.css('name').inner_text,
      'facevalue' => children.css('faceValue').inner_text
    }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
     format.json  { render :json => {:ticket => @ticket_json } }
  end
end
```

The output will something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Earlybird Ticket",
    "facevalue":"30.00"
  },
  {
    "name":"VIP Ticket",
    "facevalue":"50.00"
  },
  {
    "name":"Standard E-Ticket",
    "facevalue":"0.00"
  }
]
```

If you want to keep a `ticket` key, you can do so, just make their values an array of hashes, for example:

```
def skiddle_api
  skiddlexml = 'http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/affiliates/all.xml'
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(skiddlexml))

  @ticket_json = { tickets: [] }

  doc.css('event#12987613').css('ticket').each do |node|
    children = node.children
    @ticket_json[:tickets] << {
      'name' => children.css('name').inner_text,
      'facevalue' => children.css('faceValue').inner_text
    }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
     format.json  { render :json => {:ticket => @ticket_json } }
  end
end
```

And the output will be similar to:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "name":"Earlybird Ticket",
      "facevalue":"30.00"
    },
    {
      "name":"VIP Ticket",
      "facevalue":"50.00"
    },
    {
      "name":"Standard E-Ticket",
      "facevalue":"0.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning as well they're missing a comma between `name` and `facevalue` in the `@ticket_json` line, since they don't mention what the actual result is (if they get only a single value or if the server is crashing)...that is what is breaking my test server. Once that was fixed, then yeah, I was just typing up everything you mention.

Comment: @SimpleLime You're right, i fix it while testing but didn't mention it. Thank you! (I've fixed the answer).